# Область для выделения части изображения - plug+js?

Tags: jquery, javascript

Здравств, вот не знаю с какой стороны подойти...
Есть у меня картинка которую я получаю с сервера, 
есть вот такой плагин http://odyniec.net/projects/imgareaselect/,
это все работает, тоисть я выделяю кусочек картинки, данные отправляются на сервер и так д... С этим вопросов нет.

**Дело в том, что нужно ограничить область выделения тоисть сделать возможным выделять не всю картинку, а только ее часть
К примеру, я получил картинку а позволить выделять только определенную область, вот наглядней http://dl.dropbox.com/u/26399837/Forums/flower2.jpg**

Вот какой у меня код для выделения всей картинки. Использую jQuery.

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./jQuery/jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
    href="./jQuery/imgareaselect-0.9.8/css/imgareaselect-default.css" />
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="./jQuery/imgareaselect-0.9.8/scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="./jQuery/imgareaselect-0.9.8/scripts/jquery.imgareaselect.pack.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#target').imgAreaSelect({
        handles : true,
        movable : false,
        resizable : false,
        autoHide : true,
        onSelectEnd : function(img, selection){
            $("#target").attr("src","/JFreeeChartServlet/generateImg?x1=" + selection.x1 + "&y1=" + selection.y1 + "&x2=" + selection.x2 + "&y2=" + selection.y2 + "&width=" + selection.width + "&height=" + selection.height);    
        }
    });
});

</script>
<title>JFreeChart_Bsp</title>
</head>
<body>
    <img src="/JFreeeChartServlet/generateImg" id="target"
        alt="generateImg" height="750" width="1450" />
</body>
```

Спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

У этого плагина есть документация, причем не самая плохая. Из нее следует что вы можете следить за событием **onSelectChange**, так же как вы следите за **onSelectEnd**. Дак вот в onSelectChange можно сравнивать  selection.y1,y2,x1,x2 с допустимой пользователю зоной, и если пользователь вылез использовать API метод **setSelection**(обратите внимание что требуется передать instance: true при инициализации плагина) что-бы рамка вернулась в максимально допустимую пользователю область.

Comment: Точнее - там есть параметры для выделяемой области
> maxHeight  Maximum selection height (in pixels)
>
> maxWidth  Maximum selection width (in pixels)

Comment: нужно же еще позиция этой области а не только ее размер.

Comment: rnd_d
Интересный подход.. Но мне нужно, чтоб просто оно сразу не пускало выделение дальше чем нужно...
Так как например делают свойства maxHeight и maxWidth

Эти свойства позволяю выделять область не больше maxHeight и maxWidth!
А мне нужно определить такую область на картинке, чтоб только в пределах этой области можно было выделять..
Ситуация такова, что есть график который нужно выделять, а у меня картинка на которой кроме графика еще и легенда и оси и так д..
Спасибо.